# FilteringLogs using grep

Tags: linux, grep

HOW can i solve this problem using grep.

The output of any command or stream can be piped to the grep command. Then, grep filters this output according to the match pattern specified and outputs only the matching lines. For instance, given the following command:

ls --help | grep "dired"

Answer Format:

Look to the logs file and filter the specific string which starts with CTK?

CTK{*****************************************}

i am stuck on this problem please explain to me this further, thank you so much.

i try to put this on terminal

ls --help | grep "dired"

and it return:

-D, --dired generate output designed for Emacs' dired mode

Now how can i use the code above to get the answer in this format

Answer Format:

Look to the logs file and filter the specific string which starts with CTK?

CTK{*****************************************}

Comment: Not sure I understood you but try `grep -E "^CTK.*"`

Comment: i have already try that. but i got the wrong answer,

Comment: Then add an example dataset. Show what the desired result would be, and what it would not be.

Comment: Is that a HackerRank challenge?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format your sample input, output, and code as Code Blocks then [edit] your question to do so.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.